# Add a class to an Id when class x is in the source

Tags: javascript, class

When the class .errors is in the source then add class x to id y

You can see my example here;
https://jsfiddle.net/deamtzm7/2/

My attempt here;

```
  if ($(".errors").length) {

    $(".errors").show(
      $(#myform).addClass("fs-form-overview");
    );

  }
```

What I like to do is get the bg green because there is the class errors in the source.

It needs to add class **fs-form-overview** to id **myform**
Or even better, change class **fs-form-full** to the new class **fs-form-overview**

Comment: Have a look at this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/deamtzm7/3/).

Comment: Why are you calling `$(".errors").show()`?

Comment: @RJM, because I don't know any js coding and this was in the example X-)

Answer (score 0):

This did the job, thats to @Hilfe !

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($(".errors").length) {
      $('#myform').addClass("fs-form-overview");
      $('#myform').removeClass("fs-form-full");
  }
});
```